# Does clearing app data remove the text file which has been created by the app?

Tags: android

I want to save Settings or Configuration of my Android Application in text Files. but i need to make sure my configuration is also removed when someone "clear data",

Can someone explain to me how and why?

Comment: Yes if in the app data storage but no if it is in external based on my experience when I created on my external storage. Txt file still existing while app is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clears the App Data folder only, I.e \data\data{your-app-package}----
All the subsequent files are deleted which consists of pref files, db and other caches.

So it will depend upon where your file is created. You may use Device Explorer to be sure for ur file.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends** where you are saving the configuration file.

If you are storing it in the app's internal storage, it will be cleared. And if you are saving it in the external storage, it will persist.

So if you want to make sure it is cleared when app data is cleared, then store the file in the internal storage using `getFilesDir()` instead of `Environmennt.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Answer (score 1):

It will remove the Android Data . Which represents by package name(\data\data\your-app-package}).

```
public File getCacheDir() {
        return super.getCacheDir();
}
```

This Method returns the Dir. If you created a file or Directory Outside this Directory it will remain There even after Un-instalation.

Comment: "Outside this Directory it will remain" — what about `getFilesDir()`?

Comment: getFilesDir() refer to internal storage .